# Using ruby 1.9.2, rails3.1.0, Why am I getting an error when I try to generate a scaffold.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Basically, When I try to generate a scaffold I am getting this error
`no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)` . 
The error is coming from

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
```

Not sure why this is happening. Here is the full error:

```
/home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
/home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:125:in `const_get'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:125:in `session_store'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `block in default_middleware_stack'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:142:in `tap'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:142:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:445:in `app'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/spencer/Desktop/blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/spencer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails310/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3):

OK so what I ended up doing is this.

- uninstalled all version of ruby from rvm
- deleted all of the gemsets from rvm
- $ rvm pkg install openssl
- $ rvm pkg install zlib
- $ rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr
- reinstalled rails in a gemset

Everything works fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this: (forgive the fact that there may be errors in my paths and I'm not on my linux box)

```
cd to ~.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ext/openssl
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

Basically, just cd to the gem's source directory for your particular ruby version and rebuild/install this.

You will not need to rebuild ruby, this has been a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your in linux you could try these

```
apt-get install openssl
apt-get install libopenssl-ruby
```

Comment: This will most likely not fix the problem unless he recompiles Ruby as well. The problem is caused by the libopenssl-ruby library missing during the compilation of Ruby. If, by chance, this is still broken, then read the output of `rvm notes` which will tell you the exact packages to install.

Comment: http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/ I am trying this right now. find out in a second.... didn't work.